# How do i run ASP.NET code on a server outside of VisualStudios

Tags: asp.net

I was able to run Default.aspx but i think i am doing this wrong. I uploaded my ASPX files and Global.asax to httpdocs i did a simple test to see if there was any URL rewriting and there was none (which every page requires except for Default.aspx). I am unsure how to properly upload and run this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click your site in Solution Explorer and choose "Publish Web Site".

Comment: This was very useful. I dont have to upload as much and the bin are all in bin. However i still get errors, but this time in my default.aspx as well. I think it is closer but still has trouble with something.

Comment: Found the problems. They were related to multiple things. incorrect path was one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [Setting up your ASP.NET server (IIS)](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial25_Setting-up-your-ASP.NET-server-(IIS).html) - this tutorial will help you set up ASP.NET under IIS6.

Comment: The interesting thing about the Publish command is that you hardly need any tutorial

Answer (score 0):

You'll need IIS.

http://www.iis.net/

Comment: yes, there are many options for a web server.  not exactly sure why he'd set up a linux box just to test his web app however.

Comment: Not many professional/jobbing devs would consider running ASP.Net code under Mono. even now, at the tail end of 2010 ;-)